# Error1 0x8974002F in windows phone 8 developement using phonegap

Tags: windows-phone-8, cordova

Am using Visual studio express 2012 evaluation copy for windows phone 8 development using phonegap. I can run my application with the emulator that shows my app. When i try to deploy in device (Nokia lumia 520), i get deploy error `Error  0x8974002F`.

When deploying i get some errors in script as `Illegal syntax. Expecting valid start name character.` in `<%=`.

`<%=CompanyName %><br />`

Is this the cause for not deploying in device.

Comment: Did you inserted the usb cable properly and restart the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution by inserting the USB plug directly to the board. It worked once the USB port is changed.

For the `Illegal syntax. Expecting valid start name character.` in `<%=`, the problem is i created the html file and copied the original source to the created file.

Here the double quotes are changed as multiple double quotes like `""<%=""` by the visual studio and i identified it and cleared that got worked well.